# kernel panic: out of memory при запуске Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

Словил такую ошибку после компиляции и установки нового ядра ( стояло 15.4.0 - поставил 16.8.1). Вся установка прошла успешно и без ошибок. Но при следующем включении Ubuntu, выбирая в GRUB-e запуск под новым ядром, ловлю ошибку. С чем может быть связано ? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С тем, что вы компилировали ядро. В Ubuntu имеется пакетный менеджер - apt. Все пакеты (и тем более ядра) должны устанавливаться только через него и этот дистрибутив не рассчитан на то что юзер будет компилировать системные компоненты. Если вам так хочется компилировать, ставьте Arch.

Comment: Это не решение проблемы, а просто обход её. Я ставил на всех настройках menuconfig по умолчанию, так что думаю нигде ошибку в компиляции и установке не допустил.

Comment: @Wizardddd, а в чем собственно проблема заключается? Я не про отказ ядра стартовать, а о том, для чего на убунте понадобилось именно 16 ядро?

Comment: Это условия лабораторной работы. Изначально при скачивании стояло 15.4, если я не ошибаюсь. Надо было апгрейдить.

Comment: причин тут может быть вагон и тележка, почитайте мануалы про сборку и конфигурирование ядра под вашу версию ОС. Одна из основных причин, как мне кажется, перед компиляцией ядра, Вы не скопировали текущий конфиг ядра в новую сборку.